# web servlet method for login/register/ check HttpSession valid?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web, backend

The question is, when we make a webpage where there is user login and register button. what servlet method(doGet/doPost, or other method?) we should use for the implementation of the 2 functions in the back end? and when the user load the page, it will call the same servlet to verify if it is in the valid session, then what method for this function? 
   Can someone answer my questions and explain why?  Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Maybe show some code and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. For security reasons you never want to send credentials with the GET method, that's all I can say with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about two different things. I'll start with your first question.

> The question is, when we make a webpage where there is user login and
>   register button. what servlet method(doGet/doPost, or other method?)
>   we should use for the implementation of the 2 functions in the back
>   end?

You should handle login and register with two different servlets. As someone mentioned in the comment already, if you want to do sensitive operations (like login,delete,update) always use the post method. Because the get method will pass the parameters via the url, the post method doesn't do this. When you try load the page for a url mapped to only a post method, nothing will happen.
Some info about the differences here:

https://www.javatpoint.com/get-vs-post

> and when the user load the page, it will call the same servlet to
>   verify if it is in the valid session, then what method for this
>   function? Can someone answer my questions and explain why?

You should not call the same servlet to verify if it is a valid session. A session is created whenever someone vists your website whether they are logged in or not. Every new visit to your website creates a new session for that visitor. When a user logs in or registers this is when you associate a certain session with the user. Some info about this here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-session-tracking.htm